# How do I vertically shift letter in the text

Tags: text-decorations

I'd like to type the word TRENTo, as the acronym of something. But I'd need the letter "R" to be shifted down a little bit... Something similar to as letter "E" in the `\LaTeX` symbol. And I'd like to have it outside the math mode if it's possible.

Comment: `\raisebox{-<dimen>}{R}`, where `<dimen>` is a dimension.  You may also want to add a small negative kern before the lowered `R`

Answer (score 5):

Use `\raisebox` with a negative argument to lower text, and I suggest some negative kerning, to fill in the gaps.  Finally, stick it in a macro for convenience.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\TRENTo{T\kern-.4ex\raisebox{-.48ex}{R}\kern-.40ex ENTo}
\begin{document}
\TRENTo{} to the rescue!
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to protect it from changing to different font families or shapes due to the underlying text, then you can put it in a group with the desired font properties, as in

```
\newcommand\TRENTo{\begingroup\normalfont
  T\kern-.4ex\raisebox{-.48ex}{R}\kern-.40ex ENTo\endgroup}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `\TeX` macro definition. TeX has primitive `\lower` or `\raise` followed by dimen and box. The box is shifted by the given dimen (in horizontal mode). You tas can be solved by:

```
\protected\def\TRENTo{T\kern-.4ex\lower.48ex\hbox{R}\kern-.4ex ENTo}
```